# Index size is greater in wiredTiger compared to mmap

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I was just evaluating MongoDB.
For testing purpose i inserted 500 documents in mongoDB collection one with wiredTiger storage engine and other with mmap.

While doing stats query the `_id_` index size is greater in wiredTiger compared to mmap. Overall doc size is less in wiredTiger due to compression.

Why the index size is greater in wiredTiger?

Mongo verion 3.0 installed on windows 7